# R: how to label the x-axis of a boxplot

Tags: r

```
     apple=c(1,2,3,4,5)
     banana=c(5,4,3,2,1)
     watermelon=c(4,5,6,7,8)
     boxplot(apple, banana, watermelon)
```

If I were to plot this, the x-axis of the boxplot is labeled as 1, 2 and 3. How can I change those to "apple", "banana", and "watermelon," respectively? `xlab=` labels the entire axis, but not the individual boxplots. Which command/option should I use?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you read the help file for `?boxplot`, you'll see there is a `names=` parameter.

```
     boxplot(apple, banana, watermelon, names=c("apple","banana","watermelon"))
```

[image]

Comment: Replaced by "labels" in numpy  version 1.16.4

Comment: remember: `par(xaxt='s')` is required