# Add name to boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

This question is related to: [R: how to label the x-axis of a boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589211/r-how-to-label-the-x-axis-of-a-boxplot)

When more than one column is plotted, names appear. But when only one column is plotted, name does not appear, even when names=.. argument is used:

```
ddf = structure(list(apple = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), banana = c(5, 4, 3, 
 2, 1), watermelon = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), .Names = c("apple", "banana", 
 "watermelon"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

 ddf
  apple banana watermelon
1     1      5          4
2     2      4          5
3     3      3          6
4     4      2          7
5     5      1          8


boxplot(ddf[,1:2])
boxplot(ddf[,1])
```

[image]

[image]

Following also do not work:

```
boxplot(ddf[,1], names='apple')
boxplot(ddf[,1], names=c('apple'))
```

How can I add name to the boxplot when only one column is used? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use 'xlab':

```
boxplot(ddf[,1], xlab="apple")
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a `show.names=` argument to `bxp`, which `boxplot` calls. You can thus do:

```
boxplot(ddf[1], show.names=TRUE)
```

Make sure this is `ddf[1]` not `ddf[,1]` though, so that the name is retained.

Comment: Why show.names=TRUE not needed for multiple columns? Can this be considered a bug?

Comment: @rnso - by default there is no label for only 1 category. I wouldn't call it a bug, probably more of a deliberate design choice. Also, using `ddf[,1]` will never be able to give you a name as it will return an unnamed vector as `"["` has `drop=TRUE` by default.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `mtext`:

```
boxplot(ddf[,1])
mtext("apple", side=1, line=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The boxplot is added at `x=1` by default, so you can add at tick and axis label to `x=1` as would happen when you plot multiple columns.

```
axis(side = 1, at = 1, labels = 'apple')
```

Answer (score 1):

I also used the solution with `show.names` for Boxplot{car}. In my case I wanted to sum up some columns in one boxplot and label the outliers at the same time, hence I used `Boxplot`.

```
Boxplot(df, show.names = T, names = "test samples", labels = rownames(df), id.method = c("y"), id.n=9)
```

For `boxplot` you don't need to support a list of names for `show.names` if you are satisfied with the names of your dataframe. For `Boxplot` you have to supply a name for the plot.