# r: boxplot names="" with single vector

Tags: boxplot

I cannot get names to work in box plot.  Is it not working because I only have a single vector?  Heres what I have tried.

```
tmp = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,4,7)
boxplot(tmp)
boxplot(tmp, names=c("today"))
boxplot(tmp, names="today")
boxplot(tmp, labels="today")
boxplot(tmp, labels=c("today")
```

Answer (score 3):

`boxplot(tmp, names=c("today"),show.names=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found an alternative at the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25590238/4092304

So could be coded as ...

```
boxplot(tmp, xlab = "today")
```